# How to write a EBCDIC byte[] to file using spring writer?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a formatted ebcdic byte[] which i have created using custom code. Now I want to write to file. I am able to do this using Java. I was trying to check if i can do this using a Spring writer. 
I tried using FlatFileItemWriter . but just wrote a set of objects to file. Also the problem is that the Item writer also introduces a new line after each item. Ebcdic is however is a single stream of bytes for the entire file.
ItemWriter  ebcdicByteWriter;

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends AccountInvoice> items) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<byte[]> finalList= new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    for (AccountInvoice item : items) {  
        finalList.add(item.getEbcdicBytes()); 
    } 

    ebcdicByteWriter.write(finalList); 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FlatFileItemWriter` has a hook to change the line separator: `setLineSeparator(java.lang.String lineSeparator)`. Why not just pass it an empty String so the lines concatenate?

**EDIT:** Use a line aggregator to convert your byte array to an EBCDIC String.

```
public class BytesAggregator<byte[]> implements LineAggregator {
    @Override
    public String aggregate(byte[] item) {
        return new String(bytes, "Cp1047");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dean! now I have all of the data in a single line. LineSeparator. However I noticed that the FlatFileItemWriter always writes a String. which is causing the object string of byte[] is being written to file. Eg. [B@59ddcf86[B@42284509   instead of actual bytes

Comment: Do you know of any other Item writer that would just bytes out to file.

Comment: You don't need any other writer. Just write an aggregator like the one above

Comment: Dean, I was looking to write the bytes as is to the file and not convert it to string. It will be non human readable. And can only be decoded using a tool (EBCDIC Hex reader). Hence I was looking for writer that simply writes outs the bytes to file without any conversion.

Comment: Strings don't have to be human readable and can use _any_ encoding. The EBCDIC encoding is is `Cp1047`. I've used `FlatFileItemReader` to read and `FlatFileItemWriter` to read EBCDIC files in the past with no issues, and I would not recommend creating a custom writer when the out-of-box ones will work perfectly well. You can check the FlatFileItemWriter javadoc to confirm how to set the output encoding, but it will work.